# How do I get out of this weird zoom in/out?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

[image: zoomed in/out blender]

Can someone please diagnose this. I clicked on something on the keyboard but I don't remember what I pressed exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange!

At the lower right corner of the 3D view, under the *View* heading, there is a setting called *Lens* that is currently set to 1. That is the focal length of the viewport camera, and should be set to something like 50 (the default in the current release of Blender).

Changing that value should solve the issue.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH ITS BEEN LIKE THIS FOR A WHILE!!